# Change definition of paragraph text object in Vim?

Tags: vim, latex

I asked a question in the (La)TeX stack exchange and it was recommended to me that I see whether I could get an answer here. The question [can be found here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73325/correct-spacing-around-environments-without-the-comment-symbol-when-using-parskip).

The basic question is this: can I tell Vim to interpret the 'paragraph' text object differently? Now paragraphs are defines as blocks of text separated by a blank line, but I want to change this to blocks of text separated by a line that contains a percentage symbol (%), which is th comment symbol in LateX, i.e. that Vim understand that:

```
This is a paragraph
%
This is another paragraph
```

Answer (score 2):

No. See

```
:help paragraph
```

and

```
:help todo
```

and search for `paragraph`, where you'll find a number of entries including this:

> -   Add regex for 'paragraphs' and 'sections': 'parare' and 'sectre'.  Combine
>      the two into a regex for searching. (Ned Konz)